# Web api core returns 404 when adding Authorize attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

I am new to .net core, and I am trying to create web api core which implements jwt for authentication and authorization purposes.

Inside Startup class I configured it this way:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddDbContext<MandarinDBContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<User, Role>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyDBContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = false,
                        ValidateAudience = false,
                        ValidateLifetime = true,
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        ValidIssuer = "yourdomain.com",
                        ValidAudience = "yourdomain.com",
                        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
                            Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("My secret goes here"))
                    };

                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                });

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

        // Add application services.
        services.AddTransient<IUserService, UserService>();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

But when I try to call the following action:

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/Tokens")]
    public IActionResult TestAuthorization()
    {
        return Ok("You're Authorized");
    }
```

I get 404 not found. If I remove Authorize attribute it's working .

Could you please guide me to solve that issue?

Comment: Maybe this can shed some light: https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/issues/498

Comment: If you have *cookie authentication* on it might redirect you to a Not Found page, without it you just get a nice 401 - Authorization has been denied for this request.

Comment: [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
this is the solution

Answer (score 75, accepted):

It happens when your API is not authorized and your redirect URL doesn't exist.
When authentication fails, Web API will send a 401 code. Now if you are handling this code on the client side and doing a redirect for an authorization failure, then make sure that the redirected Url exists. 
Also, **Do not add the [Authorize] attribute to the controller that handles Authentication methods (Login/Register)**.
Your culprit looks to be the Authorize attribute. Since you are using JWT authentication scheme. Your authorize attribute should be following

```
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")]
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/Tokens")]
    public IActionResult TestAuthorization()
    {
        return Ok("You're Authorized");
    }
```

To make it default authentication scheme, Change AddIdentity to AddIdentityCore. here is a very good article.

[Using JwtBearer Authentication in an API-only ASP.NET Core Project](https://wildermuth.com/2018/04/10/Using-JwtBearer-Authentication-in-an-API-only-ASP-NET-Core-Project)

Comment: No I am not handling it on client side I am testing it using postMan

Comment: options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
Do you have something like this in your configure services code in startup.cs

Comment: No I don't have such a configuration and I am testing my endpoint using valid jwt token

Comment: Thanks alot it's working now. But I have one question can I configure that without need for providing AuthenticationSchemes parameter for every time I need to specify Authorize attribute?

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem as you, I managed to solve by modifying ConfigureServices

from this

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddJwtBearer(..)
```

to this

```
services.AddAuthentication(options => {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;})
 .AddJwtBearer(...);
```

Comment: Thank you!! This fixed the specific 404 error code (not 401) issue I was seeing trying to use `CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` and `.AddCookie()` in .NET 6 Core Minimal REST API.

Answer (score 3):

When you are using JwtBearer tokens you can add this snippet to your ConfigureServices:

```
  services.AddControllers(opt => {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder("Bearer").RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
            opt.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        })
```

This will set bearer auth policy throughout the whole application and require authenticated users on every endpoint.
Also you don't won't need to put [Authorize] on methods, and you can put [AllowAnonymous] on endpoints and controllers if you want them to be available to unauthenticated users.

Note: this works for .net core 3.1

Comment: While this did work, I ended up using the accepted answer since I could not get this to work when I needed to override and specify an authorize attribute with Roles.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I added configurations in the wrong order. Identity needs to be added before authentication.

Answer (score 1):

It may be cause the identity service registration comes after the authorization service registration in Program.cs.

It needs to be like that:

```
builder.Services.ConfigureIdentity();
builder.Services.ConfigureAuthorization(builder.Configuration);
```

Answer (score 0):

it worked with me by using just the authorize attribute

```
[Authorize]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {...}
```

by this way in ConfigureServices

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
               .AddEntityFrameworkStores<OkazContext>();

            var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Configuration["JwtConfig:Secret"]);

            var tokenValidationParams = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                RequireExpirationTime = false,
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
            };

            services.AddSingleton(tokenValidationParams);

            services.AddAuthentication(options => {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(jwt => {
                jwt.SaveToken = true;
                jwt.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParams;
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```

this is the solution