# ASP.NET Core JWT Authentication to secure webAPI [Authorize] attribute Error 401 Unauthorized

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, jwt, token, authorize-attribute

I develop API POST and it works correctly, but when I add [Authorize] attribute I got 401 Unauthorized in the postman even when I add token correct in header

```
 [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
           
            [HttpPost]
            
            public async Task<ActionResult> Post([FromBody] CViewModel cVM)
            {
    // to do
            }
```

I just want to secure my API with JWT TOKEN,
API authentication work correctly and generate a token but I can't figure why when I added
[Authorize] attribute I got Error 401 Unauthorized
in my POST API.

THANKS!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Web api core returns 404 when adding Authorize attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52038054/web-api-core-returns-404-when-adding-authorize-attribute)

Comment: thanks but no , i edit my question when I change to [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)] I got 401 Unauthorized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is I used different secret key in the startup and generate token method

Answer (score 0):

When you add `[Authorize]`, this action can only be successfully accessed if the token is carried. One of possibilities is that the url is not mathced with this route. But a more important reason is that you do not configre the login path correctlly, or the login path does not exist. So you could check the configuration in startup.

Comment: thank you for your response , i have API that work in postMan WITHOUT [Authorize] so the URL is correct and I test it with POSTMAN i just want to add object in database , when I write  [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)] I got 401 Unauthorized even when I added token in header :/

Comment: i edit my question and i added my startup

Comment: How do you send the token when using Jwt Authentication Scheme?

Comment: i have api post for  Authentication that accept email and password and return the token I added now  the code in the question