# ASP.NET Core Minimal API returns 404 code instead of 401 for unauthenticated requests to unmapped URLs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm implementing a simple ASP.NET REST API with authentication. Authentication is a custom `AuthenticationHandler` implementing basic auth like described here: https://dotnetthoughts.net/implementing-basic-authentication-in-minimal-webapi/. I'm also registering the DefaultAuthenticationScheme as described in this StackOverflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69171141/1147926.

Everything works as intended except when hitting an unmapped URL with an unauthenticated HTTP request. In this case the server returns a 404 error. I would expect a 401 response.

Note that the response also contains a `WWW-Authenticate` header added by the auth handler, but its 401 response code gets overwritten later in the handler chain.

Is it possible to change this behavior in ASP.NET Core and stop request processing when a request couldn't be authenticated successfully?

Comment: A 404 is correct, since there is no endpoint defined. If an endpoint is defined, it will execute the auth middleware, which validates if you are authenticated, and if not, returns the 401.

Comment: My problem with this behavior is that it enables information disclosure to unauthenticated parties, since they can guess URLs of defined endpoints based on the return code.

Comment: Well you can override the behaviour of what happens in the case of a 404 or 401, and then return the same result. See https://www.infoworld.com/article/3545304/how-to-handle-404-errors-in-aspnet-core-mvc.html.

Comment: The connection is not getting to your code.  The website URL is returning the error.

Comment: It seems like you want to authorize all URLs even if they don't exist? Any reason why?

Comment: @davidfowl That's right. The reason is, as I said in my comment to rotgers that this allows unauthenticated parties to probe for defined endpoints, which is a form of information disclosure.

Comment: I added an answer, let me know if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you really want to do is protect the entire site with an authorization policy.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
});
```

This will get applied if there isn't another policy to apply to the endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior for ASP.NET Core is to return a 404 if an endpoint can't be mapped. However, you can change the default behavior by adding a simple piece of [middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write?view=aspnetcore-6.0) in the startup code of your web application.

Something like this should work:

```cs
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    await next();
    if (context.Response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound
        && context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/authenticated-base-path"))
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
    }
});
```

Comment: Alright, it seems there isn't a way to achieve the desired behavior without adding some post-processing middleware. @rotgers' linked Infoworld article is similar in spirit to this answer.